# Showing loading message on form submit - back button woes

Tags: jquery, back-button

I'm showing a div with a loading message and image when a form is submitted:

```
$("#some_form").submit(function(){
  $("#some_form #loading").show();
});
```

This works as I expected. But, if you use the back button to go back, the loading div is still visible because the browser has not reloaded the page.

Is there a browser event I could use to hide the loading div when the back button is used? Or perhaps I'm going about the whole thing the wrong way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a header `Cache-Control: no-cache` telling the browser not to cache the originating page? When navigating back in the history should force it to reload the page.

How about `window.onunload` ?

Comment: window.onunload did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're showing the 'loading' image, you're probably working with AJAX. Right? You should use the ajax-start and ajax-complete events =)

EDIT:
You could try:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {

     $("#some_form #loading").hide();

 }
```

Or this:

http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/

Comment: No, it's not using ajax.. It's just trying to compensate for the fact the form is submitting to something we know might take some time to render and we want to avoid people submitting the form multiple times. I wanted to avoid changing it to use ajax just for the loading image, unless there's no other way..

Comment: onbeforeunload removes the element as expected and so stops the image being there when I go back, but it does it too early - the loading image is removed while the next page is loading (so it doesn't behave like a loading bar). Detecting the back button press would be too early in the process - I don't want to detect the back button and deal with it, I need the page it goes back to to know about it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you chould add a hash to the url. Then when something needs to be loaded, replace the hash with for example '#loading'. You could detect the change with this: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: Ahhh, onunload instead of onbeforeunload does the job! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
<script>
$(function() { 
    $("#some_form #loading").hide(); 
});
</script>
```

in your head. So it hides the div whenever the page is fully loaded. This should also work when the back button is pressed as far as I know.

Comment: This is what I initially tried, but doesn't work because the browser is using a cached version of the page and does not fully reload the page.